# Problema> too many indices for array

Tags: python

Esty haciendo una red neuronal pero obtengo un error en los datos que no me permite ejecutar el scrip. Mis datos son un conjunto de 9568 filas y 5 columnas. En formato csv delimitados por comas.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es parte del codigo que uso:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats
seed = 7
numpy.random.seed(seed)

from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
myfile = drive.CreateFile({'id': '1uJ0Y_WF1OspE46fAulNJPokdZ9gbfQYl'})
myfile.GetContentFile('EstudioCaso.csv')

dataset = numpy.genfromtxt("EstudioCaso.csv", skip_header=1, dtype="f,f,f,f,f", unpack=True, delimiter=",,")
dataset.shape
dataset.ndim
print (dataset)
X = dataset[:,0:4]
Y = dataset[:,5]
```

Los datos se leen de la siguiente fomra:
[( 8.34, 40.77, 1010.84, 90.01, 480.48)
(23.64, 58.49, 1011.4 , 74.2 , 445.75)
(29.74, 56.9 , 1007.15, 41.91, 438.76) ...
(15.99, 43.34, 1014.2 , 78.66, 465.96)
(17.65, 59.87, 1018.58, 94.65, 450.93)
(23.68, 51.3 , 1011.86, 71.24, 451.67)]

El error que obtengo es el siguente:
too many indices for array

Comment: Hasta donde puedo ver tu pregunta es sobre fallos al tratar de leer archivos csv en python. No a propósito de redes neuronales. Una pregunta mal formulada no atrae la atención debida. Hice una pequeña revisión de tu llamado `dataset = numpy.genfromtxt('este.csv', dtype= float, unpack=True)` usando unas pocas líneas similares a las de tu imagen y obtuve `array([nan, nan, nan])` **Eso sugiere que el archivo necesita un tratamiento diferente**

Comment: Pero que tipo de tratamiento podria darle es que necesito entrar esos datos para poder hacer la red neuronal sin eso es imposible y no se como tratar numpy para que me deje entrar datos con comas

Comment: Para evitar eso como puedo incertar un csv separados por como donde me reconozca cada columna. Los datos son decimales

Comment: He buscado la documentación [genfromtxt()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html?highlight=genfromtxt#numpy.genfromtxt) allí te puedes orientar mejor. Borré un comentario porque me parece que no es pertinente.

Comment: Hice nuevas pruebas. Y encontré lo siguiente: àgregué esta línea al iniciar: `from io import StringIO` y cambie el tipo de dato a leer: `dataset = numpy.genfromtxt('este.csv', dtype= str, unpack=True)` observa **dtype = str** y obtuve la lectura correcta. Me entrego un array de líneas de texto. Pero es de una sola dimensión.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luego de hacer una revisión a la documentación (ver [genfromtxt()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html?highlight=genfromtxt#numpy.genfromtxt) encontré que estás haciendo lectura como array unidimensional y, al no hacer especificación correcta del tipo de deato a importar **numpy trata de recoger la línea completa como un float** de modo que te genera un array de la forma array([nan, nan, ..., nan])

Para resolver esto debes establecer el tipo de datos con una cadena como 'f,f,f,f,f' porque vas a importar 5 columnas float y especificar como delimitador ',,' doble coma (como se ve en la imagen que muestras de tus datos).
La instrucción correcta para importarlos es

```
dataset = numpy.genfromtxt("este.csv", dtype="f,f,f,f,f", unpack=True, delimiter=",,")
```

Agrego una observación adicional (a raiz del comentario recibido):
En la imagen de los datos se muestra una primera línea de encabezados. Para saltarlos se debe usar el parametro **skip_header=num_lineas_a_ignorar** de modo que el comando debe quedar así para ignorar la primera línea que no contiene números:

```
dataset = numpy.genfromtxt("este.csv", skip_header=1, dtype="f,f,f,f,f", unpack=True, delimiter=",,")
```

Para obtener columnas especificas se puede usar el parametro **usecols = tupla_de_columnas_deseadas** De modo que los valores X e Y que deseas se podrían obtener directamente al importar así:

```
#Primeras cuatro columnas
X = numpy.genfromtxt("este.csv", skip_header=1, usecols=(0, 1, 2, 3) dtype="f,f,f,f,f", unpack=True, delimiter=",,")
#Quinta columna
Y = numpy.genfromtxt("este.csv", skip_header=1, usecols=(4) dtype="f,f,f,f,f", unpack=True, delimiter=",,")
```

Nota versiones recientes de numpy admiten que si se requiere solo una columna se pueda pasar su valor simple ej **usecols=4**
De este modo los datos tienen el formato que esperabas.

En cuanto la línea que marcaba error: Tienes un array de n líneas con cinco columnas.

Por favor perdona el ruido en los comentarios.

Comment: He editado la pregunta con la linea de codigo pero no me deja seleccionar las comunas

Comment: Revisaste el dataset. Yo lo probé en IDLE y funciona correctamente. Un detalle tu primera línea contiene encabezados. Yo la quité en las pruebas que hice para no tener que poner parámetros extra.

Comment: El dataset esta separado por ,, y los numeros con decimales.EL codigo que me propuso esta ok, pero sigo sin poder seleccionar las columnas: X = dataset[:,0:4]      Hice una correcion en  el dataset que actualizo en la pregunta

Comment: Por esa razón puse **delimiter = ",,"** de modo que te toma doble coma como separador. Vi el cambio que hiciste. Nota que la primera línea te devuelve **nan, nan, ... *nan = not a number***. Por eso mejoré la orden incluyendo **skip_header=1**

Comment: IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-25-fd336fc43c57> in <module>()
     27 
     28 
---> 29 X = dataset[:,0:4]
     30 Y = dataset[:,5]

IndexError: too many indices for array

Sigue sin dejarme obtener las columnas. :(

Comment: Como puedo obtener de ese array las columnas de forma que de la primera a la 4ta columna esten en x ; y la 5ta este en Y. Algo asi: X = dataset[:,0:4]
Y = dataset[:,5]

Comment: Voy a editar la respuesta para generar los dos valores que necesitas directamente al momento de importar. No es lo más eficiente pero sirve para ilustrar el manejo de columnas

Comment: Solucionado lo de obtener las columnas edito la pregunta y completo el codigo de la red neuronal. Aclarar que todo esto lo estoy corriendo en google colab

Comment: He editado la pregunta con el resto del codigo. Y tengo un nuevo problema>           Tensorflow - ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor

Comment: Espera Eso no es correcto. Si cambias acá la pregunta anulas la utilidad de la anterior y afectas a los usuarios potenciales. **Debes dejar esta como estaba y formular una nueva**

Comment: Esta mal el codigo?????

Comment: No sabia eso vuelvo a ponerla como estaba entonces diculpa!!!!!!

Comment: Tranquilo. Arréglala para que sea útil a otros. Formula una nueva para el caso del **tensor** y trata de clasificarla mejor. Porque todavía no sería de redes neuronales

Comment: Creo que la puse bastante similar a lo que estaba :)

Comment: Listo Gracias. Ahora has la nueva pregunta

Comment: Listo: Problema Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor